# ios proper way to update programatic uilabels with viewdidappear

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, dynamic, uilabel

Every time this tab get loaded instead of updating the dynamic label, it writes a brand new label over it.  What do I need to put in this code so that it updates it or clears the dynamic labels and then put in the new label.  I feel like its probably just a simple one line fix.  Here is a simplified version of the code:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
    {
        [super viewDidAppear:YES];
        goalArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/goal.php"];
        ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
        [request setPostValue:test forKey:@"name"];
        [request setDelegate:self];
        [request startAsynchronous];         
    }
    - (void)requestFinished:(ASIFormDataRequest *)request
    {
       ...
            for (id myArrayElement in goalArray) 
            {
                NSLog(@"y value:%i", yValue);
                UILabel *label =  [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, yValue, 80, 44)];
                label.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12];
                label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
                label.text = myArrayElement;
                [self.view addSubview:label];
                yValue += 44;
            } 
        }
```

Comment: if ur gonna vote down a comment would be nice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In requestFinished: before the `for` loop, add this:

```
for ( UIView *die in [self subviews]) {   // clear out previous label
    if ( die.tag == 123 ) {
       [die removeFromSuperview];
    }
}
```

and then inside your `for` loop, add this:

```
label.tag = 123;  //doesn't have to be 123, as long as it's an int that matches the one above.
```